# Using substr to my scenario or better function available

Tags: php, string, substr

How can I get only the first values until "-"

Like for example:
I have a string,

```
$title = "9283-returns-to-normal-in-1989";
or
$title = "83-returns-to-normal-in-1989";
or
$title = "9283231-returns-to-normal-in-1989";
```

I wanted to only get the first numerical values in that string until "-". So that, I can only get `9283`, `83` or `9283231` no matter how many values in it.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
strstr($title, '-', true);
```

Comment: Sir Thank you! I have another question, how can I then get the values after `9283231-` like `returns-to-normal-in-1989`?

Comment: you can get that from -  substr(strstr($title,'-'),1);

Comment: @Ken why dont you try explode function it will give you array of all the value like for pices[0]=9283 and $pices[1] = returns and so on